# How to set up alarm for 'n' appsCompleted Metrics in EMR per day in AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

When I set up alarm for `appsCompleted`<12 for 1 out of 1 datapoints it says that the alarm will go off in the following scenario:

`This alarm will trigger when the blue line goes below the red line for 1 datapoints within 1 day`

But it does not seem to change the threshold by adding up values per day. That is the next days threshold is still 12 and not 24. I suspect that the threshold (red line) is crossed on the first day itself and that is why no alarms are triggered even in case of failure.

`State changed to OK at [DATE]. Reason: Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 1 datapoints [Timestamp] was not less than the threshold (12.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for ALARM -> OK transition).`

[image]

If I increase the m value the n value also forced increase by the console and vice verse. How do I set up an alarm that triggers if 12 jobs didn't complete per day.

Comment: Is this a cumulative metric? Do you expect to see datapoints with values 12, 12, 12 ... or 12, 24, 36, ... ?

Comment: @Tartaglia There are 12 appsCompleted metrics each day. I want to keep a check on any failure. It'll be better non cumulative.